# System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to map the path '/' - Some web pages

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis

When running my .NET 2.0 application in localhost, I see this error when opening **some** *.ASPX pages, **other pages can display properly**.

**System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to map the path '/'**

I've tried the following:

- I run Visual Studio as Administrator
- I've reset IIS with iisreset command
- I've deleted all Temporary ASP.NET Files at C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files
- I've restarted my machine 3 times.
- I open the project through Visual Studio.

Do you know how to resolve this issue, I've searching for solutions in Stack Overflow and other forums for more than a day without success.

Comment: is the issue only for all aspx pages or only for some pages. Also apart from aspx does other extension pages have this issue ?

Comment: @programming geek: just for some pages and the site only serve ASPX pages.

Answer (score 0):

After rebooting, deleting the site, changing all kinds of configurations possible, I fixed it.

The solution:

Open Visual Studio
Open Solution
Press F5
I usually open visual studio through the sln file. Don't know why... but it worked...

Comment: I've updated my question with more things I've tried but still not working.